# accessing python dict values with line-breaking (PEP-8)

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I'm trying to access the values of a python dictionary, but the line is too long so it doesn't match PEP-8 rules. (I'm using flake8 linter on vscode)

example:

```
class GoFirstSpider():
    def __init__(self, flight_search_request):
        self.name = 'goFirst'
     -> self.date = flight_search_request["FlightSearchRequest"]["FlightDetails"]["DepartureDate"]
```

I've tried:

```
self.date = flight_search_request["FlightSearchRequest"]\
    ["FlightDetails"]["DepartureDate"]
```

and got:

```
whitespace before '['
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Can you post a example input and expected output? Thanks

Comment: Slash `\ ` lets you break the line and continue in another. You can put it inbetween `]` and `[` for example.

Comment: „and got:“ How? This is not a Python error. Does some specific tool, say an IDE, report that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, it's a flake8 error.

Comment: I don't see such an [error for pycodestyle](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) (which is used by flake8). Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: [{
 "resource": "/c:/Projects/amscraper-3/src/flights_cadger/gofirst_spider.py",
 "owner": "python",
 "code": "E211",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "whitespace before '['",
 "source": "flake8",
 "startLineNumber": 9,
 "startColumn": 65,
 "endLineNumber": 9,
 "endColumn": 65
}]

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the duplicate list to one Q&A explicitly addressing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` to break lines.

```py
class GoFirstSpider():
    def __init__(self, flight_search_request):
        self.name = 'goFirst'
        self.date = flight_search_request["FlightSearchRequest"] \
        ["FlightDetails"]["DepartureDate"]
```

Comment: From pep-8: `Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` to break multiple lines as stated in the [PEP 8 style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python’s implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long,
> multiple with-statements could not use implicit continuation before
> Python 3.10, so backslashes were acceptable for that case

In your case:

```python
class GoFirstSpider():
    def __init__(self, flight_search_request):
        self.name = 'goFirst'
        self.date = flight_search_request["FlightSearchRequest"] \
            ["FlightDetails"]["DepartureDate"]
```

Comment: I've tried it, but I get: "whitespace before '[' "

Comment: Are you sure? Try to not indent and put the `["FlightDetails"]["DepartureDate"]` part directly under `self.date`

Comment: tried it too, same error.